# Can't understand why mysql query isn't returning expected results

Tags: mysql

```
___________________________
referrer_id  | int(11)    |
---------------------------
practice_name|varchar(256)|
___________________________ 
contact_name |varchar(256)|
---------------------------  
address      |varchar(256)|
---------------------------
city         |varchar(256)|
---------------------------  
county       |varchar(256)|
---------------------------      
postcode     |varchar(256)|
---------------------------  
contact_num  |varchar(256)|  
---------------------------  
creator_id   |int(11)     |      


$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipient 
WHERE practice_name LIKE '%dental%'
OR contact_name LIKE '%couchman%'
AND creator_id = '1219676200'";
```

I would like the query to find recipients where the practice name contains 'dental' or the contact_name contains 'couchman' but only if the creator_id = 1219676200 but the query is returning all of the rows meeting either of the first 2 conditions regardless of the creator_id.

Why is the query ignoring the last condition?

Comment: Try putting parenthesis around the 2nd and 3rd condition:
SELECT * FROM recipient 
WHERE practice_name LIKE '%dental%'
OR (contact_name LIKE '%couchman%'
AND creator_id = '1219676200'");

Comment: @Steven - thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to group your conditions using `()` like below since `AND` have higher precedence over `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM recipient 
WHERE (practice_name LIKE '%dental%'
OR contact_name LIKE '%couchman%' )
AND creator_id = '1219676200'
```